Panda's value_counts() method counting missing values inconsistently
Please consider this simple dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 10]}, index = range(5))

df:
    x
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   10

Some indices:
ff_idx = [1, 2]

sd_idx= [3, 4]

One way of creating a new column by filtering df based on the above indices:
df['ff_sd_indicator'] = np.nan
df['ff_sd_indicator'][df.index.isin(ff_idx)] = 'ff_count' 
df['ff_sd_indicator'][df.index.isin(sd_idx)] = 'sd_count' 

Another way of doing the same thing:
df['ff_sd_indicator2'] = np.select([df.index.isin(ff_idx) , df.index.isin(sd_idx)], ['ff_count','sd_count' ], default=np.nan)

Notice that while the values of ff_sd_indicator and ff_sd_indicator2 are naturally the same, the missing values are printed differently (NaN vs nan):
df: 

    x   ff_sd_indicator ff_sd_indicator2
0   1   NaN         nan
1   2   ff_count    ff_count
2   3   ff_count    ff_count
3   4   sd_count    sd_count
4   10  sd_count    sd_count

I don't care about the different prints, but surprisingly the missing values do not show up in the output of:
df['ff_sd_indicator'].value_counts()

which is:
ff_sd_indicator
ff_count    2
sd_count    2

But they do show up in the output of:
df['ff_sd_indicator2'].value_counts()

which is:
ff_sd_indicator2
ff_count    2
sd_count    2
nan         1

So, what is going on here with value_counts() not counting the missing values in ff_sd_indicator while they were created by the same np.nan as the missing values in ff_sd_indicator2 were created?
Edit:
df.info() :
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------            --------------  ----- 
 0   x                 5 non-null      int64 
 1   ff_sd_indicator   5 non-null      object
 2   ff_sd_indicator2  5 non-null      object


What're the types of the two columns ? I believe you have an object type column and string type column

@akuiper, no both are objects. Edited the question.

By default value_counts drops the NaN, which can be avoided by setting dropna=False:
df['ff_sd_indicator'].value_counts(dropna=False)

ff_sd_indicator
ff_count    2
sd_count    2
NaN         1
Name: count, dtype: int64

If you check the output of:
np.select([df.index.isin(ff_idx) , df.index.isin(sd_idx)],
          ['ff_count','sd_count'], default=np.nan)

You will see however that you don't have a NaN but a string:
array(['nan', 'ff_count', 'ff_count', 'sd_count', 'sd_count'],
      dtype='<U32')

Thus the value is not dropped automatically.

Aah, you are totally right. But why is np.select creating the default values as string while the user specified default=np.nan  (which is float) while he could have done default='nan'  if he wanted a string nan? Isn't it a flaw in the np.select function?

@Saeed because numpy arrays have a homogeneous dtype, when non-compatible dtypes are mixed numpy can try to downcast. The same way, if you assign a float to an integer array, only the integer part will be used. Note that you could create object arrays, but this must be done explicitly.

Btw, the way this confused me was that I was trying to replace those missing values with 0 by df['ff_sd_indicator2'].fillna(0) but of course, it was not doing so b/c they were string nan.
